# Is there any way to change the speed of system time

Tags: windows, time, system

I've developed a program that uses a system time, and i need to test it.I am using windows 10. Is there any way to speed up system time and to test my program faster.
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "Is it possible to have my computer treat one seconds as ten seconds?", then I must admit that this is not possible.

However, it is possible to modify the system of your computer (e.g. using the commandline command `time`), so you might have do the following:

```
Have your program do the first thing
Alter the system time of your computer
Have your program do the next thing
Verify the produced results
```